# What new thing I have to add in my code for using Culture Info?

Tags: .net, cultureinfo

```
EmpCLass.dtDOB = Convert.ToDateTime(txtdob.Text, new CultureInfo("en-US"));
```

Error m getting:

```
The type or namespace name 'CultureInfo' could not be found(are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference)
```

Answer (score 3):

At first glance it looks like you're missing the Globalization reference.  Make sure you have the following using statement in your code:

```
using System.Globalization;
```